# Why the application menu bar hides under the main menu bar in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

[image]In Ubuntu 14.04 why the application menu bar hides under the main menu bar whenever we try save any files which are related to that application? How can we get rid of this?

[image: in the second image the application pinta's is completely hide under Firefox menu bar]

Answer (score 1):

You can set **Menu-bar** Showing setting from **System-settings>Appearance** in **Behavior** as follows:

[image: screen]

---

If **Title-bar overlapping** than you can move via **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ Drag Mouse with left-click** In appropriate direction.

Comment: thats the correct answer

Comment: When I opened pinta it's menu bar is completely hide under firefox as you can see the title of the tab of Firefox which I was using is appearing there

Comment: I added Alt+Drag-Mouse-with-leftclick Direction in my answer (It is called **Title-Bar** not Menu-Bar)